# Documentation tutorial error from wiki

Tags: ros, wiki, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to submit several repositories for documentation following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation

The command `rosdistro_reformat file://$(pwd)/distribution.yaml` fails with the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdistro_reformat", line 66, in <module>
    success = reformat_files(index)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/verify.py", line 58, in reformat_files
    return verify_files(index_url, _reformat_files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/verify.py", line 67, in verify_files
    index = get_index(index_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/__init__.py", line 121, in get_index
    return Index(data, base_url, url_query=url_parts.query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/index.py", line 47, in __init__
    assert data['type'] == Index._type, "Expected file type is '%s', not '%s'" % (Index._type, data['type'])
AssertionError: Expected file type is 'index', not 'distribution'
```

The error is the same if I rename `distribution.yaml` to `foo.yaml`.

I guess I could do the alphabetic sorting manually...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247809/documentation-tutorial-error-from-wiki/) by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure your version of `python-rosdistro` is up-to-date.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2016-11-11**:
Yes, `python-rosdistro` is up-to-date.